# Ordinal Logistic Regression in Python with rpy2 (Python interface for R): issue with collinear predictors

Tags: python, r, rpy2, multicollinearity

I am trying to perform an Ordinal Logistic Regression in Python calling R's mass.polr function with rpy2 (Python interface for the R language). However, I run into trouble when there are some collinear or almost collinear columns in my predictors: mass.polr automatically discards some of those columns during fitting, which causes an error when I try to get predictions on the training data.

Here is a minimum example:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

pandas2ri.activate()

mass = importr("MASS")

# dataframe with two collinear predictors (x1 and x2)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['target', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3'],
                  data    = [[   0   ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ],
                             [   1   ,  1  ,  1  ,  0  ],
                             [   2   ,  1  ,  1  ,  1  ]])

model = mass.polr('as.factor(target) ~ .', df, Hess = True) # gives warning below
'''
Warning message:
In polr(as.factor(target) ~ ., data = df, Hess = TRUE) :
  design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs

'''

r.predict(model, df, type = "class").__array__() # gives error below
'''
Error in X %*% object$coefficients : non-conformable arguments
'''
```

The same error actually happens in R as well, but there I can at least see which columns have been discarded by looking at `summary(model)`.

Instead, in Python, `r.summary(model).rx2('coefficients')` (which should display the same output as `summary(model)` in R) does not display coefficient names, but just bare values:

```
array([[4.57292582e+01, 8.25605929e+02, 5.53887231e-02],
       [2.11604944e+01, 2.85721885e+02, 7.40597606e-02],
       [3.19476895e+01, 3.60605165e+02, 8.85946531e-02],
       [5.66312792e+01, 8.93862000e+02, 6.33557296e-02]])
```

Does anyone know a way to retrieve the coefficient names in Python? Or is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Even without `pandas2ri.activate()`, the FloatMatrix that gets returned from `r.summary(model).rx2('coefficients')` does not include the variable names. However, we are able to extract those names with R's `dimnames` function. Full example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter
mass = importr("MASS")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['target', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3'],
                  data    = [[   0   ,  0  ,  0  ,  1  ],
                             [   1   ,  1  ,  1  ,  0  ],
                             [   2   ,  1  ,  1  ,  1  ]])

with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    df = ro.conversion.py2rpy(df)

model = mass.polr('as.factor(target) ~ .', df, Hess = True)

coefs = r.summary(model).rx2('coefficients')

[x for x in r('dimnames')(coefs)[0]]
```

returns `['x1', 'x3', '0|1', '1|2']`, showing x2 has been dropped.

Alternatively, you can print the full model output with `r.print(r.summary(model))`

Answer (score 0):

`r.summary(model).rx2('coefficients')` returns an object without name because you are requesting to convert R objects into `pandas` (and implicitly `numpy`) ones earlier in that script (line `pandas2ri.activate()`). Numpy arrays do not have named elements.

Using `activate` is no longer recommended. Consider using a local converter in a context instead (example with `pandas` in the doc: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/generated_rst/pandas.html).